# I'm unable to install software manually downloaded from internet

Tags: installation, 13.10, java

I'm unable to install software/programs downloaded from the Internet. I able to download wanted apps but don't know how to install them. My Ubuntu Software Center works perfectly.

I usually look for a setup icon or unpack icon after download, I extract the files but can't get around installing the program. I have tried to install 7zip but it is not installing, and I need to download Oracle Java for minecraft and other applications.
I'm use to windows automatically starting setup upon download and cant figure out how to initiate the install in Ubuntu.

I'm running ubuntu 13.10, and I need help with mentioned problem.

Comment: What exactly you tried and didn't work? 7 zip is in repos can be installed from USC or CLI and for Java probably best thing is to use installer from Webupd8 PPA.

Comment: I need to install minecraft, Not on the software center so i have to install it manually which is the problem

Comment: Download  Minecraft.jar double click it. Sorry I'm unable to see whats the problem. Or use any of PPA with pre-build installers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused when you say the software center is working perfectly. If it is, and if you're using it, it should give you a search box in the upper right.[image: Software Center]

Type in the name or the type of sotfware you're looking for,click install,

[image]

type in your password,

[image]

and the software will install automagically.

Comment: I want to install minecraft which is not on the software center, so i need to manually install it which is the trouble

Comment: can someone help me with installing software manually

Comment: I'm use to windows automatically starting setup upon download and cant figure out how to initiate the install in Ubuntu.

Comment: Google is your friend - http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/minecraft-installer-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu you don't need to look for a setup icon or unpack icon. Here you can install software in many ways like

- Using Ubuntu Software Center.
- From terminal using apt-get.
- From `.deb` or `.bin` file after downloading them manually.
- From an archive using their scripted installer, etc.

The way to install software using Ubuntu Software is already described above. To install any package from terminal, open a terminal by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+T` and type

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```

and hit enter. you will be asked for root password. Immediately after entering password the installation will begin.

- To install 7zip write in terminal

> sudo apt-get install p7zip-full

- To install something from `.deb` file type in terminal

> sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb

Comment: it says   bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

Comment: i typed   sudo apt-get install <minecraft.jar>

Comment: First of all you need to write the package name without those angle brackets. And in that way you only could install packages those are listed in Canonical default repository. To add packages that are not in the repos (it is not recommend to install packages that are not in the repos) you need to add ppa.

Answer (score 0):

Using Synaptic or Ubuntu Software Center, check for GDebi (package installer) if it's installed in your system, if it isn't so, then install it. Then you can install your downloaded packages (minecraft files in your case) using GDebi. But, personally, I wouldn't recommend to install packages that are not in the repos.